# GORM doesn't create table in one-to-many relationship between two classes

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm new to grails, and I'm trying to create something with it, but have major problems from the domain design.

Basically I'd like to make a structure like this:

- User has many Baskets
- Basket has many Users, and has many Boxes inside and can have many  Jewels
- A Box is inside a Basket, and has many Jewels inside
- Each jewel has many owners.

A user can create a Basket, inside a Basket he can put(create) a Box, and inside a Box can Put(create) a Jewel, can add/remove other User (that becomes owners too)
to the Basket and to the Jewels, if he remove himself from the Basket ownership other Users still own the basket, if no one owns the Basket the Basket disappears.

A User can delete a box, and the jewels inside end on the Basket, and a User can edit in which Box a Jewel is.

I came with those domain, but they don't seem to work, when I create a Basket it doesn't add himself to the User BasketList, nor populate the basket UserList.

```
class User{

    String name

    static hasMany = [basketList: Basket, jewelList: Jewel, kanbanCards: KanbanCard]

    }

class Basket{

    String name

    static hasMany = [userList: User, boxList: Box, jewelList: Jewel]

    }

class Box{

    String name
    static belongsTo = Basket
    static hasMany = [jewelList: Jewel]

    }


class Jewel{

    String name
    static belongsTo = Basket
    static hasMany = [userList: User]

    }
```

Any of those domain is right? What I'm missing for it to work?

**EDIT:**

So now I have modified the domains like this:

```
class User{

    String name

    static hasMany = [basketList: Basket, jewelList: Jewel, kanbanCards: KanbanCard]
    static mapping = { //added joinTable proprerty for many-to-many
        basketList joinTable: [name: "mm_user_basket", key: 'mm_user_id' ]
    }

    }

class Basket{

    String name

    static belongsTo = User //added belongsTo
    static hasMany = [userList: User, boxList: Box, jewelList: Jewel]

    static mapping = { //added joinTable proprerty for many-to-many
        userList joinTable: [name: "mm_user_basket", key: 'mm_basket_id' ]
    }

}

class Box{

    String name
    static belongsTo = Basket
    static hasMany = [jewelList: Jewel]

    }


class Jewel{

    String name
    static belongsTo = Basket
    static hasMany = [userList: User]

    }
```

When I try to create a Basket (using the scaffold create method) I have the list of all users, I select one of them, but when I save, it create a new Basket with only a name without user associated to it.

Comment: I highly suggest watching this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VUMQGrNi2F0 basically you can  all that headache and make it really simple with Sets or lists in the domain classes to get what you need from other classes. But I wonder if you are making a full on misake by using domain classes to store temporary shopping cart objects - you can use your validation bean to collect all of that and when all is good to go you process and store it - it is going to be a gigantic db if it is going to collect each time a user adds or removes something from cart

Comment: I dont need the Domain class to store temporary file.
I need all of those object to be persistent and adressable (example, a list of all baskets of a given user, that he can "open" and inside he sees all box of that given baskets).

Ill have a look at your video, im pretty sure i have a lot to learn from it, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Either User or Basket has to "own" the relationship so that new objects are cascaded to the relationship.

So you have to add to the Basket class:

```
static belongsTo = User
```

You may read details here:

https://chrisbroadfoot.id.au/2008/07/19/many-to-many-relationship-mapping-with-gorm-grails/
http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Database%20Mapping/joinTable.html

Comment: Doing this, what happens when i remove the User that created the Basket from the userList of basket?

Comment: As long as there is one other user associated this should be no problem. If you remove the last user, you will have to remove the basket aswell - but this is, as far as I understood, what you wanted to do anyway.

Comment: I've edited my question with new informations, I'm still doing something wrong, even if i followed what i read on documentation.